# Submitting form on same loaded page if the page is loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So i have a PHP page that is loaded via AJAX using the .load method.

This is then displayed on my page, however i need to be able to submit the form that is located on my second page that im loading using .load, submit this form and process the data on the same page without it reloading.

I'm very new to javascript and AJAX so i've no idea if i'm evening doing this correct using .load()

Any help would be appreciated.

page 1 is the following:

```
        
 <button onclick="Test()" type="button">Load Content</button>
 
 
 <div class="box" id="box" name="box">
        </div>
    
    
    
        <script>
function Test(id) {     
$( "#box" ).load( "test.php?id=" + id );
}
</script>
```

The second page which is test.php houses the following

```
     <form id="enrolemployee" action="" method="post">
     
     
         <div class="form-group">
    <label>Test</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Test" name="Test" placeholder="Test">
  </div>
  
  
    
         <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
          <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-custom">Submit</button>
        
        
     </form>
```

Now to submit the form on test.php i use a custom token class to generate a random hash per form submit so i can validate the data on the same page and process it through my database.

is this possible to do? or do i need to have my form then post the data through a different page?

Basically i need the entire thing to stay on PAGE 1, process the form like it normally should whilst the persons page does not reload and is always static on page 1, this should never redirect to test.php

Thankyou.

Comment: Add a [complete callback](https://api.jquery.com/load/) to the load call, and inside it use `$('#enrolemployee').on('submit', function (e) {...})` to handle the form submission, just like you would without dynamically loading the form. In there, prevent the submission event as usual, then process the form data however you like. You can also use event delegation to set up the form submission handling before it is loaded.

Comment: @ChrisG so can i just submit that form then myself? or will that reload the page, do i now need to use an AJAX post request to submit this form without reloading the data? and if thats the case what data am i passing to the AJAX post request? is there a way to post the form data itself?

Comment: In the submission handler you would use something like `$.post("some_file.php", $(this).serialize()).done(function (reply) { ... });`, this will grab the form data (since `this` points to the <form> element) and POST it to the PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

**index.php**

```html
<button onclick="Test('10')" type="button">Load Content</button>
<div class="box" id="box" name="box">
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    function Test(id) {
        $("#box").load("test.php?id=" + id);
    }

</script>
```

**test.php**

```html
<form id="enrolemployee" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Test</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Test" name="Test" placeholder="Test">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-custom">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $("#enrolemployee").on('click', e => {
        // Avoid reloading page
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>);
    })

</script>
```